# Nested content within Telerik tabstrip

Tags: telerik, grid

I am having trouble with nesting content within a Telerik tabstrip.  Within my tabstrip I have a Telerik grid.  I want to use the clienttemplate to display a dropdownlist within one of the grid columns.  The tabstrip looks like this (content removed for brevity):

```
tabstrip.Add()
    .Text("Products").SpriteCssClasses("label-info")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "background-color: #ffffff;" })
    .Enabled(false).Selected(true)
    .Content(@<text>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Products", "FeeSchedule", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", id = "indexForm" }))
    }
    </text>);
```

I have a Telerik grid nested within the tabstrip tab:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<FB_LOOKUP_PRODUCTS>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:80%" })
    .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert())
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(m => m.PRODUCT_ID))
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
        .Select("_ProductsTest", "FeeSchedule")
        .Update("UpdateOrder", "Grid")
        .Insert("UpdateOrder", "Grid"))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(m => m.PRODUCT_NME).Width(300).Title("Products");
        columns.Bound(m => m.PRODUCT_ID).Title("Product ID").ClientTemplate(
            @<text>
                @RenderTabStripContent()
            </text>
        );
        columns.Command(commands => commands.Edit()).Title("Edit").Width(70);
    })
    .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Pageable()
)
```

I am trying to use a @helper template (@RenderTabStripContent()) to display a dropdown list within a grid column.  Here's what the template looks like:

```
@helper RenderTabStripContent()
{
    @<text>
        @(Html.Telerik().DropDownList()
            .Name("PRODUCT_ID")
            .BindTo(new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewBag.Products, "PRODUCT_ID", "PRODUCT_NME", "Select..."))
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:250px;" })
        )
    </text>                   
}
```

I am unable to get this working.  I keep getting the following markup error:

Parser Error Message: Inline markup blocks (@

Content

) cannot be nested.  Only one level of inline markup is allowed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try replacing this :

```
columns.Bound(m => m.PRODUCT_ID).Title("Product ID").ClientTemplate(
    @<text>
        @RenderTabStripContent()
    </text>
);
```

with this:

```
columns.Bound(m => m.PRODUCT_ID).Title("Product ID").ClientTemplate(
        RenderTabStripContent()
);
```